# Checking for NaN with math library in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan

If I assign a value, `'some value'` to one index of a dataframe, the other indexes for that column return `NaN`. I would later like to loop through the dataframe index and change the value from `NaN`. I am trying to check with the `math.isnan()`, but it wants a float as in input. What function can I use to perform this check?

```
import pandas as pd
import math
BabyDataSet = [['Bob', 968], ['Jessica', 155], ['Mary', 77], ['John', 578], ['Mel', 973]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])

df.ix[1, 'MyValue'] = 'some value'

for index, Name in df.iterrows():
    if math.isnan(df.ix[index, 'MyValue']):
        df.ix[1, 'MyValue'] = 'some other value'
print df
```

Desired Output:

```
     Names  Births     MyValue

0      Bob     968     some other value

1  Jessica     155     some value

2     Mary      77     some other value

3     John     578     some other value

4      Mel     973     some other value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `pandas` own [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df.fillna('some other value')
```

If you want to change only a specific column you can provide a dictionay:

```
df.fillna({'col_name': 'some other value'})
```

You can even change NaNs in different columns to different values:

```
df.fillna({'col_a': 'some other value', 'col_b': 'other value'})
```

Comment: if I only want to fill that one column does, `df['MyValue'].fillna('some other value')` work?

Comment: Refer to the documentation I linked to. 
You can even replace NaN in different columns with different values.
`df.fillna({'col_a':1, 'col_b':2})`
I also edited my answer.

Comment: to use `df.fillna({'MyValue': 'some other value'})`, why does it need to be assigned to `df` such as `df = df.fillna({'MyValue': 'some other value'})`?

Comment: what about replacing `NaN` only for a certain index?

Comment: @user2242044 If you know the column and index than you can just set it manually, `fillna` doesn't help you.

Comment: so my example would is really simple, but I have a another column for Male or Female. I would like to replace NaN with different values based on the gender column.

Comment: In this case you will have to explicitly iterate over the df and see if you find `NaN` then replace it based on the other column:

https://repl.it/tx1/0